# setting contstant value in dropdown list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, dropdown

I want to declare a constant value and want to set that value to a drodownlist.

I am trying like this.

```
 public class Utility
{   
    public static string DEFAULTSHIFT = "Night"; }
```

And in my dropdown based on several condition I am setting the value like that

```
cboAddShift.SelectedValue = Utility.DEFAULTSHIFT;
```

but the value of cboAddShift is still holding the value "Day".

what exactly I am doing wrong here?

Comment: show us the different conditions you mention

Comment: How the `cboAddShift.datasource` is defined and does it consist of 'Night'?